# Is there a way to reference a view inside itself in a conditional statement in xml(or atleast use the view's properties)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, data-binding, android-viewbinding

I am trying to make changes to a view based on its state onFocused like

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

...

```
android:hint="@{isFocused ? 'right' : 'left'}"
```

but it says that : cannot find identifier isFocused. Now i know that there is a way to do this using java/kotlin code, but i want to know if i can reference a view inside itself and use its properties to determine its actions. Something like:

```
android:hint="@{this.isFocused ? 'right' : 'left'}"
```

Comment: have you tried `android:hint="@{viewId.isFocused ? 'right' : 'left'}"` ? view Id will be id of your View i.e  data binding generated camel-case name for that view .

Comment: it shows following error::: Could not resolve the two-way binding attribute 'isFocused' on type 'com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout'

Comment: But i can reference the view... which completes the answer... thanks

Comment: Well as a alternate you can have a variable set at top and use it. you have to set the variable at runtime from code .

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid that but looks like i will have to do that.

Comment: I did android:text="@{tvPasswordAstg.text ?? \`name\`}" ... now this is  a text view that should either show "Password" or "Name" but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I think for the `isFocused` thing you need and Observable field because it will change dynamically . So just have a ObservableBoolean and u should be good to go . u need to chnge the value from code with FocusChnageListener .